# How to assert that two Lists<String> are equal, ignoring order

Tags: java, assertj

I am using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) and I am trying to assert that two `List<String>` contain same strings, ignoring the order.

```
List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("Something-6144-77.pdf", "d-6144-77.pdf", "something-6144-78.pdf", "Something-6144-8068.pdf");
List<String> actual = new ArrayList<String>();

assertThat(actual.size()).isEqualTo(expected.size());

// This line gives the error: "The method containsExactlyInAnyOrder(String...) in the type ListAssert<String> is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)"
assertThat(actual).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(expected);
```

How can I fix the compilation error below that is appearing when trying to use `containsExactlyInAnyOrder()`?

> "The method containsExactlyInAnyOrder(String...) in the type ListAssert is not applicable for the arguments (List)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message gives you the solution:

```
The method containsExactlyInAnyOrder(String...)
```

`String...` is a any number of strings but can be passed as an array as well:

```
assertThat(actual).containsExactlyInAnyOrder((String[]) expected.toArray(new String[expected.size()]));
```

The cast is necessary here and that code is given under the assumption that the `expected` element is created different than in your example, as it doesn't make sense to convert an array to a list and back.

Here some documentation to *varargs* (Arbitrary number of arguments, the `...`): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 18):

Both the answers ([by jlordo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056267/1421925) and [by dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056246/1421925)) work, but are workarounds rather than the correct way to do it.

There is a method in the AssertJ library for specifically checking if a `List` contains all values, regardless of order, in another `Iterable`. It is called [`containsOnlyElementsOf()`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnlyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable)):

> `public SELF containsOnlyElementsOf(Iterable<? extends ELEMENT> iterable)`
>   Same semantic as `ObjectEnumerableAssert.containsOnly(Object[])` : verifies that actual contains all the elements of the given iterable and nothing else, in any order.
>   Example :
>   `Iterable<Ring> rings = newArrayList(nenya, vilya);`
>   `// assertion will pass`
>   `assertThat(rings).containsOnlyElementsOf(newLinkedList(nenya, vilya))
>                   .containsOnlyElementsOf(newLinkedList(nenya, nenya, vilya, vilya));`
>   `// assertion will fail as actual does not contain narya`
>   `assertThat(rings).containsOnlyElementsOf(newLinkedList(nenya, vilya, narya));`
>   `// assertion will fail as actual contains nenya`
>   `assertThat(rings).containsOnlyElementsOf(newLinkedList(vilya));`

So, this method is the one you should use, like below. There is no need to cast or transform your `List` to an `Array`.

```
assertThat(actual).containsOnlyElementsOf(expected);
```

---

As a side note, your assertion on the size of the list is redundant:

```
assertThat(actual.size()).isEqualTo(expected.size());
```

This is already covered in the assertion that the lists contain the same elements.

Finally, if you do need to assert that a list has a specific site, AssertJ has a built-in method for this ([`hasSameSizeAs()`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#hasSameSizeAs(java.lang.Iterable))):

```
assertThat(actual).hasSameSizeAs(expected);
```

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of [assertj](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj) there is a [containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/ObjectEnumerableAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf-java.lang.Iterable-) for exactly this purpose. 
Your example boils down to

```
assertThat(actual).containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(expected);
```

Comment: And if that method is not available, make sure you have actually used `import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;` and not one of its cousins from other packages.

Answer (score 4):

Since the method takes `String...`, you should pass an array instead of a list:

```
String[] expected = new String[] {
    "Something-6144-77.pdf"
,   "d-6144-77.pdf"
,   "something-6144-78.pdf"
,   "Something-6144-8068.pdf"
};
```

or call it with the list of items inlined:

```
assertThat(actual).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(
    "Something-6144-77.pdf"
,   "d-6144-77.pdf"
,   "something-6144-78.pdf"
,   "Something-6144-8068.pdf"
);
```